# Cannot send commands to Docker unix socket via Python

Tags: python, docker, unix-socket

I have a script that send signals to containers using `nc` (specifically the openbsd version that supports `-U` for Unix domain sockets):

```
echo -e "POST /containers/$HAPROXY_CONTAINER/kill?signal=HUP HTTP/1.0\r\n" | \
nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

I wanted to see if I could avoid the openbsd `nc` dependency or a `socat` dependency, so I tried to do the same thing in Python 3 with the following:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect('/var/run/docker.sock')
sock.sendall(str.encode('POST /containers/{}/kill?signal=HUP HTTP/1.0\r\n'.format(environ['HAPROXY_CONTAINER'])))
```

I don't get any errors raised from the Python version, however my container doesn't receive the signal I'm attempting to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bash version, `echo` provides an additional new line. HTTP requires two new lines after the headers, so the Python `sendall` needed a second `\n` like so:

```
sock.sendall(str.encode('POST /containers/{}/kill?signal=HUP HTTP/1.0\r\n\n'.format(environ['HAPROXY_CONTAINER'])))
```